# What is the equivalent C# code for this Canon SDK C++ code snippet?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

What is the C# equivalent of this C++ code?

```
private:
    static EdsError EDSCALLBACK ProgressFunc (
                        EdsUInt32   inPercent,
                        EdsVoid *   inContext,
                        EdsBool *   outCancel
                        )
    {
        Command *command = (Command *)inContext;
        CameraEvent e("ProgressReport", &inPercent);
        command->getCameraModel()->notifyObservers(&e);
        return EDS_ERR_OK;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any C# specific constructs here. With the proper APIs, this should work as C++.

Comment: @Michael - I believe OP wishes to see a C# equivalent of whatever this does

Comment: I think the OP has this code as C++ and is trying to convert to C#, not the other way around. That said, it should work, but you'll need to use the `unsafe` keyword since you're using pointers.

Comment: Lol, I believe you are correct. Make a bit more sense that way as this would have had to be unsafe with those pointers in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a *rough* translation for illustration purposes:

```
private static void ProgressFunc(uint percent, object context, out bool cancel)
{
    Command command = (Command)context;
    CameraEvent e = new CameraEvent("ProgressReport", percent);
    command.GetCameraModel().NotifyObservers(e);
    cancel = false;
}
```

(`EdsError` has been changed to `void`, because we use exceptions in C# instead of error codes; `EDSCALLBACK` is defined as `__stdcall` which is irrelevant here; the code only works if all implied classes and methods exist; idiomatic C# would be the use of `event`/EventHandler<T>/EventArgs instead of a "NotifyObservers" method; I assume you don't want to do any interop with C++).

Comment: We use exceptions in C++ too. That looks like COM to me or a similar interop API - nobody would use a void* without a seriously good reason.

Comment: Indeed, just illustrative.  The odds that this will work are zero.

Answer (score 4):

Reading between the lines - there is a.Net 2.0 wrapper (including source code) for the Canon SDK [here](http://www.blocks4.net/Products/_net_wrapper_library_for_canon_rc_sdk/ProductDetails.aspx#DetailedDescription) and another [here](http://torrez.us/archives/2005/04/12/350/)